# iOS ARC, Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration

Tags: iphone, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

***Hello,***

When I insert this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I receive this error on line 2:

Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration

I know it has to do with the ARC, but what is an alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, and add `QuartzCore.framework`. Once you add this import, `CALayer` would be fully defined.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was a REAL help :)